# vue-router and pagination links

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have simple pagination for search results:

```
<ul class="pagination" v-if="lastPage > 1">
    <li v-for="pageNumber in lastPage">
         <router-link :to="{params: {page: pageNumber}}">${pageNumber}</router-link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I try to integrate it with vue-router. It's my router instance:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    history: true,
    routes: [
        { path: '/:producent/:type/page/:page' },
        { path: '/:producent/page/:page' }
    ]
})
```

So I would like to have urls: `/mercedes/sedan` or just `/mercedes` for 1-th page of results and `/mercedes/sedan/page/x` or `/mercedes/page/x` for others.

At this moment my links works and are generated properly only, when I open url `/mercedes/sedan/page/1`.

If I open `/mercedes/sedan` all of my router links are also `/mercedes/sedan`.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I think it's not elegant, but works... I check url containst `/page/` string, and then I just add `params` (if true) or I add it to the router path.

```
<router-link :to="{params: {page: pageNumber}}" v-if="$route.path.indexOf('/page/') >= 0">${pageNumber}</router-link>
<router-link :to="{path: $route.path.replace(/\/$/, '') + '/page/' + pageNumber}" v-else>${pageNumber}</router-link>
```